# Variable not visible in partial

Tags: templates, go

Why is the `title` attribute of my `page` object not populated in the header template ?

here is my small go program

```
package main

import (
  "html/template"
  "os"
)

type Page struct {
  Title string
  Body  string
}

func main() {
  f, _ := os.Create("index.html")
  defer f.Close()

  page := Page{"I'm the title", "And I'm the body"}

  t := template.New("post.html")
  t = template.Must(t.ParseGlob("templates/*html"))
  t.Execute(f, page)
}
```

here is the templates/post.html file:

```
{{template "header.html"}}
<article>
  {{.Body}}
</article>
{{template "footer.html"}}
```

and my templates/header.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{.Title}}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
```

for the sake of completeness, my footer, templates/footer.html file:

```
<footer>
&copy; 2015
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

The .Body variable in the templates/post.html template is filled, but the .Title in the templates/header.html template is empty, I think it's because it's a partial, rendered from another template...

How to make this work ?

I posted the complete above example as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/astropanic/92df9bb7995ad2151508)

Comment: possible duplicate of [golang template - how to render templates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546896/golang-template-how-to-render-templates)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `{{template "header.html"}}` form doesn't pass any data.

Try `{{template "header.html" .}}` instead.

See the Actions section of [`text/template`](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) for details.