# Golang: What's the pre-requisite to use {{ template "partial.html" . }}

Tags: templates, go

```
import "os"    
import "html/template"
...    
t, _ := template.ParseFiles("login.html")
t.Execute(os.Stdout, data)
...
login.html:

{{ template "header.html" . }}
<form ....>...</form>
{{ template "footer.html" . }}
```

no output, no error.

If I remove those two lines of {{ template "..." . }}, I could see the  part being outputed.

What's required to make {{ template "..." . }} work or am I misunderstanding html/template completely?

Comment: It *looks* like you may be assuming the `template` action can take a filename; it can't. It refers to a named template already parsed (via `template.Parse…`, `someOtherTemplate.Parse…` or via a `define` action of a parsed template). See the ["Associated Templates"](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Associated_templates) section of the `text/template` package documentation.

Comment: @DaveC This link http://gohugo.io/templates/go-templates/ seems to suggest it can; however it was from a google search, I wonder if that was some syntactic suger added by hugo.

Comment: possible duplicate of [golang template - how to render templates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546896/golang-template-how-to-render-templates)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to define a name for the file that will contain the other templates and then execute that.

login.tmpl

```
{{define "login"}}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
..
{{template "header" .}}
</body>
</html>
{{end}}
```

header.tmpl

```
{{define "header"}}
whatever
{{end}}
```

Then you parse both those files

```
t := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("login.tmpl", "header.tmpl"))
// and then execute the template with the defined name
t.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "login", data)
```

Comment: t := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("login.tmpl", "header.tmpl")); t.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "login", data)