# Variable Inside Define Template in Golang

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I have 3 files here in Golang project, the idea is to render the index.html isnside the body of layout.html. It works.

But when I tried to pass a variable into the **index.html**, the `console.log()` did not rendered. When I move the `console.log()` to **layout.html**, I can see the content of the JSON from `.tes`.

Here are the project files.

**layout.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{{.title}} | {{.project_name}}</title>
</head>
<body style="width:100%; height: 100%; overflow-x: visible">
<div id="wrapper" style="width:100%; height:100%; margin: 0 auto">
    {{template "contents"}}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.html**

```
{{define "contents"}}
<script>
    var x = {{.tes}};
    console.log(x)
</script>
{{end}}
```

**router.go**

```
func init() {
    // handler
    http.HandleFunc("/", RenderPage)
}

func RenderPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tes := map[string]interface{}{
        "item":"TEST3",
        "count":4567,
    }
    Data := map[string]interface{}{
        "title":"TEST1",
        "project_name":"TEST2",
        "tes":M.ToJSON(tes),
    }
    tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles("page/layout.html", "page/index.html")
    X.CheckError(err)
    err = tmpl.Execute(w, Data)
    X.CheckError(err)
}
```

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546896/golang-template-how-to-render-templates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In layout.HTML, you need to pass the context.  You do that with a `.` dot.

```
    {{ template "contents" . }}
```

Alternatively, you can pass the value of whatever var you want:

```
    {{ template "contents" .tes }}
```

...and within the contents template, the dot context will be just the value of `.tes`.  That helps limit the scope of sub-templates, not having to dot-walk to get to a value.

Comment: Thank you for the answer eduncan911. I also find out that if I use `{{ template "contents" .tes }}`, I should use `var x = {{.}};` instead of `var x = {{.tes}};`