# Golang HTML repeater

Tags: html, go

I am trying to create an HTML template that includes a table.
Each row in the table should represent a struct I have and include values from that struct.

The only relevant reference I found is this: [golang template - how to render templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546896/golang-template-how-to-render-templates)

The difference is that I don't know in advance the number of rows in the table, so I need to be able to loop through a dyanmic list of structs I have, and for each such struct populate its values into a template representing a row and add that row to the parent template representing the table.

Can anyone show me how this can be done? Any other approach is also welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're just looking for `{{range}}`, right? E.g.

```
package main

import "log"
import "os"
import "html/template"

type Highscore struct {
    Name  string
    Score int
}

func main() {
    const tpl = `<ol>
{{range .}}
    <li>{{.Name}} - {{.Score}}</li>
{{end}}
</ol>
`
    scores := []Highscore{
        Highscore{"Steve", 50},
        Highscore{"Jim", 40},
    }

    scoreTemplate, err := template.New("scores").Parse(tpl)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = scoreTemplate.Execute(os.Stdout, scores)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```